# Store links into variable instead of text file

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I am on very early learning curve of C#. I have a code for storing web links into text file. How I can store them into variable so I can loop through them later in the code and access each one separately?

```
        string pdfLinksUrl = "https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/";

        // Load HTML content    
        var webGet = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        var doc = webGet.Load(pdfLinksUrl);

        // select all <A> nodes from the document using XPath
        // (unfortunately we can't select attribute nodes directly as
        // it is not yet supported by HAP)
        var linkNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

        // select all href attribute values ending with '.pdf' (case-insensitive)
        var pdfUrls = from linkNode in linkNodes
                      let href = linkNode.Attributes["href"].Value
                      where href.ToLower().StartsWith("https://www.nordicwater.com/product/")
                      select href;

        // write all PDF links to file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\pdflinks.txt", pdfUrls.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pdfUrls` holds all of your URLs, you are using it when you are writing all of them into the file

You can use a foreach loop in order to loop through the URLs easily:

```
foreach (string url in odfUrls.ToArray()) {
    Console.WriteLine($"PDF URL: {url}");
}
```